# Regex to remove non-alphanumeric characters and all characters after dot?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a regular expression (php) to remove the forward slash, the dot and eveything after the dot in my string so that

```
$str = "ab/12c.3de";
```

becomes

```
$newstr = "ab12c";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation in regex:

```
$str = "ab/12c.3de";
$newstr = preg_replace('~/|\..*~', '', $str);
//=> ab12c
```

- Regex: `/|\..*`
- `/` matches literal `/`
- `|` OR (alternation)
- `\..*` matches a dot and everything after it

Replacement is just by empty string.

Comment: That was quick! Thank you very much! I really appreciate that you explain in detail.